# Batch file to replace user-specified text in different batch file with different user-specified text

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch file (Management Servers.cmd) which automates the opening of multiple RDP sessions, including user names and passwords.

However, the passwords on the remote servers have to be changed on a regular basis, so I am looking to create a second batch file to change the passwords within the first batch file.

I presume I need to use FOR, but as I want the user to be able to specify the text to find (eg Enter old password:) and the specify the text to replace with (eg Enter new password:), I don't know where to start.

I can't find any examples where the user of the batc hspecifies what to find and what to replace with.

Also, the find and replace needs to be case sensitive, for obvious reasons.

Thanks,
Jem

Comment: Why you don't just use a parameter to specify the password or read the password from a text file? This method is simpler...

Comment: @Aacini The password is the same for all the remote servers, but I don't want the user to have to enter the password. I have set it up with the password, but this is changed every 90 days.

Comment: So the password is stored in your first batch file literally? why is there even a password then?

Comment: I didn't suggested that _the user_ enter the password, but that the first Batch file execute the second one with the password in the parameter, or that the first Batch file (or you directly by hand) create a text file with the password and the second Batch file just read it...